# Uniform limit of continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Consider $$f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$$ on $[-1,1]$

I know $f_n(x) \rightarrow \vert x \vert$ pointwise on $[-1,1]$

How to prove this convergence is also uniform? That is, how to make $$\Big\vert \;\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} -\vert x \vert \;\; \Big\vert $$ as small as possible? Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a,b \ge 0$, we see $$(a+b)^2 \ge a^2 + b^2 \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, a + b \ge \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.$$ This shows that $$\sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 n} \le \lvert x \rvert + \frac 1 {\sqrt n}.$$ It's also clear that $\lvert x \rvert \le \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 n}$ and thus $$0 \le \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 n} - \lvert x \rvert\le \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$ shows that $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 n} \to \lvert x \rvert$ uniformly for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: you mean $M_n=sup \; \vert f_n - f  \vert = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0$, so the convergence is uniform ?

Comment: Exactly. Rather, I only showed that $$\sup \lvert f_n - f \rvert \le \frac{1}{\sqrt n},$$ but of course, the bound is achieved at $x = 0$.

Comment: ok Thank you sir!

Comment: @ User8128: From this $f_n$, we also conclude that $C^1[-1,1]$ is not complete under supremum norm. Since each $f_n$ is continuously differentiable and $f_n \rightarrow \vert x \vert$, so $f_n$ is Cauchy but the uniform limit $\vert x \vert$ is even not differentiable (at 0), so $\vert x \vert \notin C^1[-1,1]$. Am I right sir?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} -\vert x \vert =\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} -\vert x \vert\right) \frac{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} +\vert x \vert}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} +\vert x \vert} = \frac{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}- x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}} +\vert x \vert} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\lvert x\rvert \leq f_n(x) \leq \lvert x\rvert + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\qquad \forall x\in[-1,1]\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
the second inequality e.g. by observing that, for any $x$,
$$
\left(\lvert x\rvert + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^2 = f_n(x)^2 + 2\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{\sqrt{n}} \geq f_n(x)^2\,.
$$

Comment: This one helps too! thanks!